# Wrapping ETH calling the WETH contract

Tags: solidity, tokens, erc-20

I am trying to automatically wrap ETH when a user deposit ETH on my dapp. Therefore I am trying to call the WETH contract (on the Kovan Testnet for now). I wrote this code :

```
WETH9_ WETH = WETH9_(0xd0a1e359811322d97991e03f863a0c30c2cf029c);
address WETHAddress = 0xd0a1e359811322d97991e03f863a0c30c2cf029c;


//Deposit ETH to the user account on the app, the value is in wei
function depositETH() public payable{ 
    require(etherBalance[msg.sender] + msg.value>etherBalance[msg.sender], "Overflow in the Ether Balance"); 
    WETH.deposit(); //who is paying the fees ?
   // WETH.deposit.value(msg.value);
    //WETHAddress.call.value(msg.value).gas(3000000);
    //WETHAddress.transfer(msg.value);
   // WETHAddress.delegatecall();
    emit Deposit(msg.sender, msg.value);
    etherBalance[msg.sender] += msg.value;
}
```

The other contract I am trying to call have this code :

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.18;

contract WETH9_ {
string public name     = "Wrapped Ether";
string public symbol   = "WETH";
uint8  public decimals = 18;

event  Approval(address indexed src, address indexed guy, uint wad);
event  Transfer(address indexed src, address indexed dst, uint wad);
event  Deposit(address indexed dst, uint wad);
event  Withdrawal(address indexed src, uint wad);

mapping (address => uint)                       public  balanceOf;
mapping (address => mapping (address => uint))  public  allowance;

function() public payable {
    deposit();
}
function deposit() public payable {
    balanceOf[msg.sender] += msg.value;
    Deposit(msg.sender, msg.value);
}
function withdraw(uint wad) public {
    require(balanceOf[msg.sender] >= wad);
    balanceOf[msg.sender] -= wad;
    msg.sender.transfer(wad);
    Withdrawal(msg.sender, wad);
}

function totalSupply() public view returns (uint) {
    return this.balance;
}

function approve(address guy, uint wad) public returns (bool) {
    allowance[msg.sender][guy] = wad;
    Approval(msg.sender, guy, wad);
    return true;
}

function transfer(address dst, uint wad) public returns (bool) {
    return transferFrom(msg.sender, dst, wad);
}

function transferFrom(address src, address dst, uint wad)
    public
    returns (bool)
{
    require(balanceOf[src] >= wad);

    if (src != msg.sender && allowance[src][msg.sender] != uint(-1)) {
        require(allowance[src][msg.sender] >= wad);
        allowance[src][msg.sender] -= wad;
    }

    balanceOf[src] -= wad;
    balanceOf[dst] += wad;

    Transfer(src, dst, wad);

    return true;
}
```

}

I have tried all the options with commentaries on my code, none seems to work. The only one which seems to call the other contract at some point is WETH.deposit() but the msg.value is 0 even thought the first msg.sender send a msg.value of 0.1 ETH

It does not seem like a very difficult task but I am lost :(
Thank you for any kind of help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you want this:

```
WETH.deposit.value(msg.value)();
```

Your commented out code was missing the parentheses to actually call the `deposit` function.

Answer (score 5):

For solidity > 0.6.0 use

```
WETH.deposit{value : msg.value}();
```